# OLE Compound Documents in Python

Tags: python, ole

how would you parse a Microsoft [OLE compound document](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/OLE_Compound_File) using Python?

**Edit:** Sorry, I forgot to say that I need write support too.. In short, I have an OLE compound file that I have to read, modify a bit and write back to disk (it's a file made with a CAD application)

Comment: I have the same problem. OleFileIO_PL is a good way to read, but does not support write. However, the module is written in python and the source is online so you could possibly try to make a writable version. Then there are also other packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found [OleFileIO_PL](http://www.decalage.info/python/olefileio), <s>but it doesn't have write support.. :/</s> and as of version 0.40 (2014) it **has** write support.

**Edit:** Looks like there's a way (though Windows-only) that supports writing too.. The [pywin32](http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/) extensions ([StgOpenStorage](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/pythoncom__StgOpenStorage_meth.html) function and related)

Comment: See http://www.endurasoft.com/vcd/ststo.htm for more hints on usage of the Win32 native calls

Comment: Yeah I was gonna say that Windows as a native API to handle storage documents.

Comment: The library has now been extended to support writing.  The new implementation is simply called `olefile`.  http://www.decalage.info/python/olefileio

Answer (score 2):

An alternative: The xlrd package has a reader. The xlwt package (a fork of pyExcelerator) has a writer. They handle filesizes of 100s of MB cheerfully; the packages have been widely used for about 4 years. The compound document modules are targetted at getting "Workbook" streams into and out of Excel .xls files as efficiently as possible, but are reasonably general-purpose. Unlike OleFileIO_PL, they don't provide access to the internals of Property streams.

```
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt
```

If you decide to use them and need help, ask in this forum:

`http://groups.google.com/group/python-excel`

Comment: Could you provide an example for reading and writing an arbitrary stream from an OLE2 file?

Answer (score 0):

For completeness: on Linux there's also the [GNOME Structured File Library](http://projects.gnome.org/libgsf/) (but the default package for Debian/Ubuntu has Python support disabled, since the Python bindings are [unsupported since 2006](http://git.gnome.org/browse/libgsf/tree/python/README-python)) and the [POIFS](http://poi.apache.org/poifs/index.html) Java library.